# Not able to deleteOne() on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-deleteone

Tryin to delete this document from my collection:

***db.users.find({"dref._id": "USER_ONE", "dref.age" : 23, "school": "BRHS"})***

When I search it using the find, i get it. I'm trying to use this for delete it:

***db.users.deleteOne({"dref._id": "USER_ONE", "dref.age" : 23, "school": "BRHS"})***

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Any error message returned ?

Comment: nope, just 0 records deleted

Comment: We probably need more context to see what's going on. Are you using a read-only account to access? or are you doing the operation on a secondary replica? These are 2 likely reasons that you cannot do a delete but you can read/find the document